# Integrating:$\int\limits_0 ^ {\infty}e^{-x^2}\ln(x)dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral, euler-mascheroni-constant

$$ \displaystyle \int_0 ^ {\infty}e^{-x^2}\ln(x)dx = -\frac{1}{4}(\gamma +2\ln(2))\sqrt{\pi} $$
This is a well known integral.
But I want to know how to solve it??
Also, please refrain using contour integration etc, as I don't know it.

$\gamma $ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Comment: Is it allowed to use any integral identity for $\gamma$, or what do you know about $\gamma$?

Comment: @mickep I just know the basic definition of the euler mascheroni constant and some integrals that are equivalent.

Comment: Maybe you can use the integral equivalence $\gamma = -4 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}x \ln(x) dx $.  Then replace $\gamma$ in your equation and combine the integrals, then integrate.

Comment: @rVitale that'll work but from where did that integral come from??

Comment: @Kunal  $\gamma$ can be defined by a convergent integral, and then it is equal to a bunch of other things, and appears in integral expressions.

Comment: @Kunal you'll have to pick a definition of $\gamma$ before trying to show your expression above gives an equivalent definition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Differentiation under the integral sign gives a pretty fast way. Let:

$$ I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\right).\tag{1}$$
Our integral is just $I'(0)$: since $\Gamma' = \psi\cdot\Gamma$,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\log(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{4}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\color{red}{-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\left(\gamma+2\log 2\right)}.\tag{2} $$
$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$ is well-known and $\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ can be computed from $\psi(1)=-\gamma$ and the duplication formula for the $\psi$ function:
$$ \psi(z)+\psi\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right) = -2\log 2+2\,\psi(2z).\tag{3} $$

Comment: The way i would go, very nice. On the other side, thinking hard for some time i don't find another one. would be very interested

Comment: Looks like I will have to learn about digamma functions!